# PS3 Hard drive corrupted file system. Stuck in safe mode "preparing" message

Tags: technical-issues, ps3

Netflix caused the PS3 (slim, latest firmware) to hang during playback. It wouldn't turn off so I had to cut power. As expected when it started again I had the file system corrupted message but this time, PS3 could not repair and notified me formatting is my only option. Turned to safe mode, tried to restore the file system from there, and it is just stuck on "Preparing" for ever. I waited over night (twice) and no progress. No HDD access light flashing, nothing.

I've tested the drive for bad sectors and found none. The drive is mechanically fine. 
Our backups were, by twist of fate, deleted a short while ago and not recreated. 
Me and my sons are gutted we might be loosing hours upon hours in saved game play. I'm trying to save the day, but it looks bleak.

Is there any way I can either repair the file system or copy our saved games off the drive? 
I've went through all the forums and it seems like nobody has a solution that works for us (though most posts are a few years old).

Comment: This will be very hard for us to answer for you as it would require your drive to verify if our steps actually work or not. Everything I have read is against you though.. Not many OSes can read the format of the PS3's file system and even after that the files are encrypted. While there is apparently a tool that can decrypt them I am not a very trusting person so I did not try them. Basically though if its a hardware failure then making a ghost/clone/image of the drive and trying would not help and if its a data issue (cant decrypt) a clone of it would fail as well anyways. Sorry.

Comment: As far as I found out, the process to read the drive involves flashing a custom firmware, downgrading it to some version, grabbing a key file, and using it to read the drive. Although I can do that, this is not really something I want to do. I was hoping there would be a way to fix the filesystem.

Comment: @James You wouldn't likely need to decrypt the files, as long as the filesystem metadata has survived. The filesystem used by the PS3 is UFS2, for which there are many advanced repair utilities, since it is also the filesystem used by FreeBSD (which the PS3 system software is based on). See also [this](http://www.psdevwiki.com/ps3/Harddrive).